# How can I see the full list of commits and not only the recent ones?

Tags: git, github, version-control, versioning

I am trying to see the full list of commits on a branches comparison I need to work on in order to do a new release.

It is only showing 250 commits and it seems to be that there are `385 commits`. That's what the left top tab says.

So how can I visualize those 385 commits?

[image]

Comment: Maybe out of Bitbucket, in local CLI? Clone the repo locally if you don't have it, and make the diff with whatever difftool you prefer. Depending on your context, might be a possibility to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the command `git log --graph`
Or `git reflog`